# oracle dbms_scheduler privileges issue

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

In my DB I set up 2 schemas, schemaA and schemaB. 
In schemaA I create a job (jobA) and a procedure (procA) to set arguments and enable the job. I test the flow in schemaA and it's working correctly. 
In schemaB I need to call schemaA.procA in order to run the job. I grant to schemaB the privileges needed to execute schemaA.procA but the error **ORA-27486: insufficient privileges** is raised. 
Debugging procA I locate the exception at the beginning of dbms_scheduler instructions (DBMS_SCHEDULER.PURGE_LOG(job_name=>jobName);).

**EDIT**: Add informations as requested in the comment

*VERSION* : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

*GRANT* : system @ mydatabase

`grant CREATE ANY JOB, CREATE EXTERNAL JOB , CREATE JOB to schemaA;`

*PROCEDURE* : schemaA @ mydatabase

```
procedure procA ...
...    
DBMS_SCHEDULER.PURGE_LOG(...);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(...);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE(...);
DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(...);
...
end procA;
```

*GRANT* : schemaA @ mydatabase

```
grant execute on procA to schemaB
```

In procA there are others operations that are correctly executed until PURGE_LOG that raise the exception

Comment: Please post a sample of the procedure code you are using, a script of the exact privileges you granted, and the exact version of Oracle you are using. There are a number of things that could be an issue here. Also, DBMS_JOB is not part of Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Inspetting others users I found that I miss one system privilege :

```
MANAGE SCHEDULER
```

Granting it from sys the procA run successfully both from schemaA and SchemaB